# Android Material Design Datepicker with AppCompat

Tags: android, datepicker, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm trying to add the new Android 5.0 Material Design Datepicker to my pre 5.0 application using AppCompat. I've added

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"
```

to my build.gradle file and updated my Theme to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

but the Datepicker still looks like this: 
 [image: old datepicker] 
And not like this: 
[image: material design datepicker]

Can anybody tell me how to get the new datepicker to work on pre 5.0 devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't unless you port it by your own...

Comment: @Selvin ic, thank you. Spinner, Checkbox etc do work with appcombat. the android fragmentation is getting ridiculous and annoying.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about such details... Pre 5.0 android's users don't know about new date picker :-)... Also you should be happy that compat library exists and you don't have to worry about more important stuff like fragments, action bar....

Comment: @Selvin yeah, maybe you're right. thanks.

Comment: As I wrote, you can try to port it...  Fx from android 21 source...

Comment: Did you manage to get the new datepicker to pre 5.0 devices? The calendar app is using it so it should be possible

Comment: @user1354603 Please take a look at my answer below. It's possible to do it using a 3rd party library.

Comment: Selvin could you tell what is the procedure to port it from 21's source?

Comment: @Selvin cay you please tell about getting the material design calendar dialog in the pre-lollipop devices, I didn't understand about "porting" you are talking about.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update:

As well pointed out by jfcartier, there's now also [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker). It's probably a nicer solution than the one below since it has a nice themable API.

---

You could try the [android-betterpickers](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) library. It has a `CalendarDatePickerDialog` widget that looks like the one you want. It provides a light and a dark theme, but for customizing colors you'd have to add it as a library project and change the code yourself.

Usage is pretty straightforward once you add the library to your project.

```
    // Create date picker listener.
    CalendarDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new CalendarDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialog dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            // Set date from user input.
            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            date.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            date.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            // Do as you please with the date.
        }
    };

    // Create dismiss listener.
    CalendarDatePickerDialog.OnDialogDismissListener dismissListener = new CalendarDatePickerDialog.OnDialogDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDialogDismiss(DialogInterface dialoginterface) {
            // Do something when the user dismisses the dialog.
        }
    };

    // Show date picker dialog.
    CalendarDatePickerDialog dialog = new CalendarDatePickerDialog();
    dialog.setOnDateSetListener(dateSetListener);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(dismissListener);
    dialog.setThemeDark(false);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER_TAG");
```

The end result should look like this (sorry for the poor quality).

[image: AOSP Calendar Picker]

Comment: How can we set the our custom style to calederpickerdialog in this library?? How can we change the colors and all?? Please help.

Comment: @Sajal You need to download the source code and add it as a library to your project. Then you can customize anything you want through code. You could also try overriding colors and styles by creating resources with the same name in your project, but that's a more limited approach.

Comment: Worked for me,except the onDismissListener.

Comment: Thanks @jfcartier! For beginners like me: If you use @jfcartier link - you should import "com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;", "com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;" and "com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;" in your to make the the activity recognize the relevant code.

Comment: I can not find CalendarDatePickerDialog but CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

### Material components is the recommended way for date picker

With the `Material Components for Android` you can use the new `MaterialDatePicker`.

add the following to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

**For kotlin**

```
 val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
 val picker = builder.build()
 picker.show(parentFragmentManager, "date_picker_tag")
```

**For Java**

```
   MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = 
   MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
   MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
   picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

It supports the following configurations

**portrait - mode date picker**

[image]

**landscape - mode date picker**

[image]

**date range picker**

[image]

**Mobile input picker**
[image]

**Additional reference**

[Here](https://material.io/components/pickers/#mobile-pickers) is the official design guideline

A complete demo app can be found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/datepicker/DatePickerMainDemoFragment.java)

Comment: Thanks, but you forgot to describe select date listeners. See https://ahsensaeed.com/android-material-design-library-date-picker-dialog/.

Comment: the official docs for explaining how to use this thing is atrocious. https://material.io/develop/android/components/picker

Comment: You can't embed this one directly into a ViewGroup. You can show it as a dialog, either full screen or not.

Answer (score -2):

I liked [this](https://github.com/jaydeep17/datetimepicker) library. It's a clone of [Flavien Laurent Date and Time Picker](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) with some improvements. Both of them are based on [Official Google Date and Time Picker for Android 4.3+](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/) but adapted for Android 2.1+.