# Can we display lollipop style DatePicker in kitkat Devices?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to display lollipop style datepicker in 4.4.2 device can anybody give me some idea where to start or is it even possible?

Comment: doesn't that come with the theme?

Comment: yes you can if you port it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362971/android-material-design-datepicker-with-appcompat

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad...could you please tell me more about how to port it ?

Comment: https://github.com/CiTuX/datetimepicker

Answer (score 6):

As more people switch to the Material design, it's good to have an answer as a reference.

First of all,
the date picker DOES NOT come with the theme on pre-Lollipop devices

But good news are, you don't have to port the library yourself, others have done it already.

Check https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker 
or https://github.com/CiTuX/datetimepicker

Both libraries support android version 4.0 and up (API level 14).
I've personally tried the 1st one and it works great.

Comment: Please note that "Material DatePicker" is not the same as "Lollipop DatePicker": in each Android release the pickers have a slightly different graphic style, so you must consider the exact style you want when you choose the library to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

For those who supports Android 2.1+ and/or uses `support-v4` library or `AppCompatActivity` from `support-v7` I suggest [this library](https://github.com/jaydeep17/datetimepicker). 
It's a clone of [Flavien Laurent Date and Time Picker](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) with some improvements. Both of them are based on [Official Google Date and Time Picker for Android 4.3+](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/) but adapted for Android 2.1+.

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker is working only with Android 4.0+ and its `DatePickerDialog` extends `android.app.DialogFragment` which is useless if you are using `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` because it works with fragments extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.