# Material Design datepickerdialog

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I would like to know if I can implement material design datepickerdialog for my android app

**Code**:

```
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    public class SelectDateFragment  extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    EditText mEdit;
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
          return   new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
         populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }
    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
         mEdit = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.date);
         mEdit.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    }
    }
```

Simply, I dont want to use third part libraries.I just want to know if it can be done using android support libraries and how.

Comment: I hope This will help u alot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362971/android-material-design-datepicker-with-appcompat

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

a good Material Date Picker Library.
Easy to use.

Just add compile'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.4.2' to your app: build.gradle

for example: Date Picker Dialog

```
// Show a datepicker when the dateButton is clicked
    dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                );
                dpd.setThemeDark(modeDarkDate.isChecked());
                dpd.vibrate(vibrateDate.isChecked());
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            }
        });
```

and get your picked date from its implements method 'onDateSet' function

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
        dateTextView.setText(date);
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to implements the **DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListene**r with your activity. Because the first argument in DatePickerDialog newInstance method refer OnDateSetListener.

Comment: Don't forget to assign listeners to an activity or a fragment on device rotation like here: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3779 and turn off vibration and permission: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/55.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have material design pickers in lower versions, the support library does not have these widgets. You will have to use 3rd party libraries. You can try this library, the author took the `DateTimePicker` from Android Framework which you see in `Android Lollipop` and compiled into a library and it supports from Android 4.0 on wards.

To add it in your app just add below lines in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.4.1'
}
```

Find it on github [link](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker)

The code taken from Android Framework can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but it would be a little troublesome to explain here. As a tip you could use a library such as [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1531).

Although the Google recommends that you use the native Date picker from the os version. They claim that the user would be more familiarized with the proccess.

Best of luck.

Comment: Can you cite where does Google recommend this?