# coloraccent does not work with datepicker android

Tags: android, datepicker

I have declared material theme in my `styles.xml`.

```
  <style name="SignUpMaterialTheme.Base"       
  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/splashBg</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#f2efea</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#f2efea</item>
  </style>
```

I am using `EditText` with `TextInputLayout`, so when I click on it I am showing a `DatePickerDialog`. Now the problem I am facing is the date selected color is showing as white, but I have already declared the color `accent` in my style. When I tried removing the `colorControlNormal` and `colorControlActivated` it shows the date selected as the `accent` color but the `TextInputLayout` color changes to black. What to do?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to sure... Did you set your style like app or activity theme?

Comment: yes in manifest for that activity

Comment: It's strange. Do u create it [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362971/android-material-design-datepicker-with-appcompat)?

Comment: It will better if u post a code where u create `DatePickerDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

for light color:

```
DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,year,month,day);
```

for dark color:

```
DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);
```