# Difference between these two types of Datepicker dialog

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

Hi i have been working with the datepickerdialog in android and i got the 1st dialog as o/p. However how to get the 2nd image like Datepickerdialog. Is it purely depends on Android OS version? I am using 6.0 device to test it.

The code which i used is

```
 new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Comment: As you said it depends on your OS version, however you can use emulators to check all the different versions and his layouts

Comment: From which version the second type of datepicker is included in android?

Comment: i have 5.1 , and i get the second type of date picker dialog.

Comment: @KarthikKPN above lollipop. But you can achieve both with just little customizations.

Comment: As you said it depends on your OS version, however you can use emulators to check all the different versions and his layouts

Answer (score 1):

There are two date widgets in the current Android system DatePicker and Calendar view. The DatePicker has been in use since API 1 but Calendar view was only introduced in API 11. The main difference between the two is the way that they look. As they work in much the same way and the DatePicker is more versitle this is the widget we will use.

**As long as you use the latest API and the default layout it will show in a calender format (2nd image in ques):**

if you run your app on an older pre-Lollipop version of Android then you will see the Holo themed spinner version (1st image).

**You can opt to display the holo spinner version in all Android versions by setting the datePickerMode to spinner.**

As an alternative you can also opt to also show a full Calendar in spinner mode by setting CalendarViewShown to true. The spinnerShown property can also be set to false to remove the spinners.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting second dialog using this code on 6.0

```
 final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                      int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                    eventDate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                    CityText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Main2Activity.context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
                        //If keyboard is VISIBLE then Hide it
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }
                }
            };


            assert eventDateParent != null;
            eventDateParent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(Main2Activity.context, date, myCalendar
                            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    Date d = null;
                    try {
                        d = sdf.parse(String.valueOf(sdf.format(new Date())));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(d.getTime());
                        dpd.show();



                }
            });
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Dude,, it's a default DatePickerDialog. This code will generate diff. view of calander in diff os versions.

Comment: I know but as I mentioned above , I'm getting second dialog

Answer (score 0):

On Pre Lollipop version you will see the first one. 
If you still need the second one you will need to use some librabry I guess.

This answer might help..
[Android Material Design Datepicker with AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362971/android-material-design-datepicker-with-appcompat)